# Why do only men have Adam's Apples? What is it? What function does it serve?

Tags: swallow-swallowing, function, male, sexual-diamorphism

Why do only men have Adam's Apples? What is it? I mean, I know what it looks like, but I don't understand what it is made up of and what role it plays in the male body. Is it the larynx??

What function does it serve? Is it used for swallowing?

Since it's only part of the male anatomy, it's a part of sexual-dimorphism, but why wouldn't women need it? Or is it just not as noticeable in women?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adam's apple, in conjunction with the thyroid cartilage which forms it, helps to protect the walls and the frontal part of the larynx, including the vocal cords (which are located directly behind it). It is found in both women and men. ... Consequently, the laryngeal prominence grows in size mainly in men.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_apple

For more information on the origin of the Adams apple, visit:
http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/07/why-the-adams-apple-is-called-the-adams-apple/